# behavior of new 'each @array' in scalar context

Tags: arrays, perl, iteration, new-operator

Perl 5.14 gives us the extended `each` function which operates on arrays as well as hashes:

> When called in list context, returns a 2-element list consisting of the key and value for the next element of a hash, or the index and value for the next element of an array, so that you can iterate over it.  When called in scalar context, returns only the key (not the value) in a hash, or the index in an array.

An example using list context works:

```
perl -E 'say $^V'

v5.14.0

perl -E '@a = (1..10); while (my ($i, $elem) = each @a) {say "\$a[$i] = $elem"}'

$a[0] = 1
$a[1] = 2
$a[2] = 3
$a[3] = 4
$a[4] = 5
$a[5] = 6
$a[6] = 7
$a[7] = 8
$a[8] = 9
$a[9] = 10
```

however in scalar context, I get nothing:

```
perl -E '@a = (1..10); while (my $i = each @a) {say $i}'
```

Can anyone offer any insight? I have a feeling that this will be a head slapper when someone points out my error, but perhaps not.

<s>Edit: In fact the `while` loop has nothing to do with it:</s>

```
perl -E '@a = (1..10); $i = each @array; say $i'
```

gives no output either. `s'@array'@a'` oops.

Edit 2:

As per daxim's comment:

```
perl -MDevel::Peek -E'@a = (1..10); Dump each @a'

SV = IV(0x161ce58) at 0x161ce68
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (TEMP,IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 0
```

however I have no idea what that tells me.

Edit 3:

It seems that the loop exits because the first index is `0`, or false. I have filed a bug ( http://rt.perl.org/rt3/Ticket/Display.html?id=90888 ) since this doesn't seem to be the desired behavior.

Comment: Add the output of `perl -MDevel::Peek -E'@a = (1..10); Dump each @a'` for a hint.

Comment: @daxim, thanks for introducing me to `Devel::Peek`, it looks to be quite useful!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to do `while (defined( my $i = each @array )) { say $i }` otherwise it'll stop at the first index (0) since it is false.

Comment: Makes sense, though unfortunately cumbersome! Why doesn't `perl -E '@a = (1..10); $i = each @array; say $i'` work then?

Comment: Because you're setting @a but querying @array?

Comment: Though, you had me doubt myself there for a second, because I just copy/pasted it to my terminal ;)

Comment: What would you think about my filing a feature request that `each @a` return `0 but true` on the first element of an array (provided the array has any elements)?

Comment: See my comment to your comments on ikegami's answer. I think the bug is that there isn't an implicit defined() for arrays, while there is for hashes. Since stopping for arrays immediately if there isn't an explicit defined doesn't strike me as a valid feature and seems indeed like a bug.

Comment: Err, forgot part of a sentence there: Since it seems indeed like a bug, I'd say yea, please file a ticket :)

Comment: @Joel: not a good idea; better to extend the automatic adding of defined() to while(scalar assign from each)

Comment: @ysth, that is what we ended up deciding (the conversation spilled into comments on ikegami's answer, see it there)

Answer (score 1):

[ The contents of this post are wrong. There must have been a bug in my test. I'm not deleting it due to the presence of good comments. ]

<strike>`scalar each %hash` works thanks to each hash having an iterator associated with it. I suspect that such an iterator wasn't added to arrays.</strike>

<strike>This is a bug, as `each` says:</strike>

> <strike>When called in scalar context, returns only the key (not the value) in a hash, or the index in an array.</strike>

<strike>Please file a report using `perlbug`.</strike>

Comment: as answered by phaylon, it turn out it works just fine, the iterator is there. Unfortunately, the first index, `0`, is false, so the `while` iterator dies. This is really unfortunate, I was looking forward to easily iterating over array indexes, and iterating over defined is a different, if somewhat better hoop.

Comment: perhaps could `each @array` return the much maligned `0 but true` on the first index? I would be happy to file that feature request.

Comment: ... this would be the 'least confusion' I believe

Comment: `perl -MO=Deparse -E'...'` tells me that `while (my $i = each %h)` is deparsed as `while(defined(my $i = each %h))`, but the same isn't true for arrays. So, yea, that maybe something you want to take up with @p5p.

Comment: perlbug sent (my first one!)!